# Calculate all possible combinations in array and display them in table php

Tags: php

I have an array which looks like

```
[1] = [1,2,3]
[2] = [1,2,3]
[3] = [1,2,3]
[4] = [1,2,3]
```

How can I calculate all possible combinations of numbers with condition, that only one number in array element can be selected.

Finally, I need to get smth like this:
1111
1222
1333
1122

And so on..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So it is always `[1,2,3]`, or can it vary within this array? If it can then this would be the worst example you could have given. If it cannot then the array doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Please explain condition detail or show more example

Comment: it always 123, number of rows can be different.

Comment: and only one number in a row can be selected